# Mixed up columns when loading multiple CSV-Files with Dask

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I tried to import a bunch of csv-files with dask and it seems like my columns are mixed up.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

names = ['date', 'country', 'A', 'B']

dtypes = {'booking_date': object, 'booking_country': object, 
      'A': object, 'B': np.float32}

dask_df = dd.read_csv("folder/file_*.csv", dtype=dtypes, 
                       header=None, names=names, skiprows=1)
```

The dataframe has the following shape:

```
        date country    A         B
0  2019-07-24     ALB  XX  0.041786
1  2019-07-24     AND  XX  0.022168
2  2019-07-24     ARE  YY  0.177757
3  2019-07-24     ARM  YY  0.024475
4  2019-07-24     AUT  ZZ  0.287205
```

When I want to continue to work with it it seems that column A and B are mixed up for some columns. Does anybody know why this can happen and how I can avoid it?

If I use glob.glob to create a list of files and then for-loop through it with pandas I don't have this issue. Could it be that the glob-way of doing this is interpreting the headers for each file whereas dask isn't in case the columns are mixed in my input dataset?

Thank you very much in advance!

Tim

Comment: Hey @Tim, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us what this "mixed up" dataframe looks like?

Comment: Thanks! :) The columns would be date, country, B, A instead of date, country, A, B ...if I create a list of files with glob.glob and use a regular for-loop i don't get this issue. But i need to sort out that the input-files have in case the same schema all the time. (speaking about hundreds of files, that's why it's not that straight forward to check)

Comment: Cool, I think this is in fact my issue. Thanks for it :) https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-dask.ipynb

Comment: Can you try by providing the dtypes as an OrderedDict?

Comment: Hey, I did, but it didn't solve the issue. Some of my input-data files have the wrong order of columns and dask probably doesnt check the schema of each file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

Apparently some of my files have a wrong order of columns, which dask can't handle.
https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-dask.ipynb will fix the issue, but I didn't had the time to test it yet.